# Example of ring which is neither commutative nor unital

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Give an example of ring which is neither commutative nor unital.

I think, subring of matrix ring is neither commutative nor has a unit element.

Answer (score 2):

I think your idea should work if you for example take all $2\times2$ matrices with entries from $2\mathbb Z$ (i.e. even integers).

Answer (score 1):

The subring of the quaternions $\{a + bi + cj + dk\}$ containing the elements whose coefficients $a, b, c, d$ are all in $k \mathbb{Z}$ for any integer $k \geq 2$.

Any group ring $R[G]$ where the group $G$ is nonabelian and the ring $R$ has no unit.

Answer (score 1):

$M_{2 \times 2}(2\mathbb{Z})$ is a non-commutative ring without identity.

Comment: Welcome on the MathSE! The site support Latex. :-) Put the latex expression between to \$s.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be an infinite set and let $S$ be a ring with unit (not necessarily commutative).
Let $R$ be the set of $A \times A$ matrices with entries in $S$ and with only a finite number of non zero entries.
Then $R$, with the usual sum and multiplication of matrices, is a non commutative ring without unit.